# Modify binary to expand array size

Tags: c++, linux, assembly

I have a binary file that I need to adjust slightly to increase the size of an array from a length of 32 to a length of 64. The purpose for this is that I am trying to run a game using very specific hardware that the game does not natively support due to a limit on the number of buttons on a joystick being set to 32 while my hardware registers as a joystick with 48 buttons. When I launch the game, I get a stack overflow and the game crashes.

I want to be very clear that this has nothing to do with cheating. I am trying to play a single player rhythm game using an arcade cabinet's dance stage instead of, say, an Xinput controller. This game natively supports a "dance" mode but not my exact hardware.

I do not have access to the actual project code as I am not an employee of the company that developed or published the game, but I do know what the problem code looks like (see below C++ example). I've run the game through `gdb` and disassembled the problem function (see below asm code). I've noted a few points of interest in the asm but I am by no means an expert, or even a beginner to be honest, with assembly so I would truly appreciate anyone who could help me tweak this binary.

What I have attempted so far is to adjust `+9` and `+448` from `0x5c` to `0x7c` and then adjust the `cmp` on `+240` from `0x20` to `0x40`. This has lead me to a memory access violation; not the desired effect~

I would finally like to note that this task was done in the past on an older version of the game but that `bspatch` file seems to be lost to time. The original binary editor noted that he "simply adjusted the length of the array" but did not give any more detail than that. My assumption is that this single function needs adjusting, but perhaps someone more knowledgable than myself can read the assembly and tell me if I need to do more digging around.

[C++ Code](https://github.com/chrismingay/CM-XMAS-2012/blob/master/xmas.build/glfw/main.cpp#L2895-L2935)

[ASM Code](https://hastebin.com/uwejuvowat.asm)

Edit: Solution found!

@geza noticed that the stack has a reserve of 16 unused bytes and that my joystick has 16 buttons more than the array in C++ accounts for. So we adjusted the `cmp` in the button loop from `0x20` to `0x30` on +240 and disabled the stack overflow protection by `nop`ing out the `jne` on +442. A bit dirty, but the game seems to be functioning just fine. :)

[Updated ASM](https://gist.github.com/karai17/1b0d93d9cb8390016363e51c3390442d)

Comment: It could be simpler to restrict the number of buttons reported for your joystick.

Comment: This is true, however I want all of the buttons to respond. the driver for my hardware registers the entire arcade cabinet as one single joystick, so both player 1 and player 2 controls are combined into one device.

Comment: If the array is allocated on the stack this shouldn't be too hard. If it's a global array though then it might get tricky.

Comment: You need to fix other things as well. For example, at +18, there is a code which puts a stack-end marker, and it is in pair with +431. And maybe there is other things as well. Check out all the `esp` related memory accesses.

Comment: @AndrewSun In the C++ code, the array is created locally in the function. I am not quite sure how well that translates to asm though.

Comment: @geza Thanks you for that information. Should I adjust those values from `0x4c` to `0x6c`?

Comment: Yes. Basically, you'll need to check out all the `esp` references. Ones that below that array need to be kept as they are. Ones that after the modified array needs to be fixed by +0x20 (just another example: at +28, 0x70 need to be modified to 0x90. And maybe that's all).

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand. The "loop" that fills the array is at +229, so I need to adjust that `cmp` to `0x40`. Are you saying that the block in memory that is reserved for the button array is allocated much earlier (+32?) and that +28 is the only area that needs adjusting?

Comment: All the stack variables are allocated at +9 in one go (that line basically means to allocate 0x5c bytes from stack for all local variables. Then all local variables are accessed by esp+some_offset. For example `x` is at `esp+0x24`, `buttons` is at `esp+0x2c`, etc.). I'm not saying for sure that +28 is the only additional modification needed. Apply the modifications, and check out what happens :)

Comment: "+28 is the **only** area that needs adjusting?" No. +229 needs to be modified as well (that loop clears the button array). And +28 too.

Comment: Thanks, I think that helps me understand a bit more what is going on. Let me know if I am understanding this correctly: the buttons array that I am trying to extend starts at `0x2c` (+229) and extends to `0x6c` for a total of 64 bytes. So anything that is currently shown to be below `0x6c` such as +28's`0x70` needs to also be adjusted. Anything above `0x6c` is fine as it is.

Comment: Exactly. (with the only exception that maybe I'd use the words *below* and *above* reversed. For me, `0x70` is above `0x6c`, as its address is larger. But I'm not sure about this terminology, I'm not a native english speaker.)

Comment: You're right. The stack builds from the bottom up, I used the words incorrectly. As for the issue, I adjusted +28 to `0x90` and I am still getting memory access violation. You suggested +229 may need to change as well?

Comment: Oops, sorry. No, don't modify +229. I thought you mean the cmp at +240. Maybe I'll create list, what I see that need to be modified :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182676/discussion-between-karai17-and-geza).